# Expand just first level of an expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Is there a way to build a function to expand just the first level of powers and products of an expression?

Edit:

$$\text{ExpandUpToLevel}\left[\left(\left(x^2+1\right)^2+1\right)^2,1\right]=\left(x^2+1\right)^4+2 \left(x^2+1\right)^2+1$$

Expand and ExpandAll just expand everything. Better yet would be to expand up to the desired level.

Comment: minimal input and expected out?

Comment: The form of your equation is `Equal[Power[..], Plus[..]]`, so the only power in the first level is the left-hand side of the equation.  Is that what you exactly what you want expanded?

Comment: The RHS is what I want after applying the function to expand just the first level to the LHS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I might need more examples to figure out how to automate the level accurately.  This works on the given example (in V10):

```
Map[Inactivate, (1 + (1 + x^2)^2)^2, {2}] // Expand // Activate

(*  1 + 2 (1 + x^2)^2 + (1 + x^2)^4  *)
```

Why level 2?  Let's look at the tree form of the expression:

```
(1 + (1 + x^2)^2)^2 // TreeForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What we see is that the `Plus` inside the `Power` we want to expand is at level 1.  If we inactivate it, no expansion will occur.  So we have to inactive beginning at level 2.

Comment: Hmm new in 10? Nice one. I need to read the release notes :)

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
CExpand[Power[exp_Plus, n_]] := 
Sum[Binomial[n, k] First@exp^(n - k) CExpand@Power[Drop[exp, 1], k], {k, 0, n}]
CExpand[exp_] := exp
```

Another idea, which works more generally, is to use

```
Replace[exp,{a_Plus->CPlus@@a,b_Power->CPower@@b},{2,Infinity}]
```

This replaces the build-in functions by some undefined ones, which Mathematica will not expand. You can now apply Expand and then substitute the original Plus and Power to obtain the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
expr = ((x^2 + 1)^2 + 1)^2;

Expand[Map[Defer, expr, {2}]]
Expand[Map[HoldForm, expr, {2}]]
Block[{df}, Expand[Map[df, expr, {2}]] /. df -> Identity]
(* 1 + 2 (1 + x^2)^2 + (1 + x^2)^4  *)
```

You can also use the second argument of `Expand`:

```
Expand[expr, Cases[expr, _Power, {2}][[1]]]
Expand[expr, _[___, _^_, ___]^_]
(* 1 + 2 (1 + x^2)^2 + (1 + x^2)^4  *)
```

Comment: Yes, I saw this one, but then you have to deal with the patterns for each case.